# Installing OSX: file system verify or repair failed

Tags: macos, installation, restore

After I've pressed cmd + R at start up, I try to reinstall. It takes about 20 minutes before I get an error saying:

```
file system verify or repair failed
quit the installer to restart your computer and try again
```

I've tried to First Aid through Disk Utility, but then i get this error:

```
First aid process has failed. if possible back up the data
on this volume. Click done to continue.
```

And Disk Utility Erase gives this:

```
The disk disk1 couldn't be ejected
Couldn't unmount disk.
Operation failed..
```

Does anyone know the solution to this? My mac has been freezing and bugging out a lot lately, so I'm very much looking forward to a clean slate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accessing Disk Utility after trying to download gave me the error. I restarted the machine and went directly to disk utility and erased the disk, that solved the problem.